# Choose FS format in Tortoise SVN or/and in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tortoisesvn

I work with Tortoise SVN for versioning the code. I have the last version installed (1.7.10).
I created the local repositories using this tool.

Recently I installed the last version of EasyEclipse for PHP (1.2.2.2), when I try to connect to the Repositories I get this error:

> Unsupported FS
>
> format svn: Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'

How can I specify the correct FS format in Tortoise or in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Really you can't.

And I'll suggest don't use EasyEclipse at all, because it expect ancient format of repo (2 is "pre-1.5"), while more recent versions (of repo-formats) have serious improvements in different areas

Comment: Thanks. So, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Memochipan - [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/releases/releases.php?release=juno) (due to presence of "PHP Development Tools" and "Subversive" /which have support for 1.7 WC of SVN/ )

Comment: I was not able to find a Juno Package with PDT. For that reason I don't know if I can trust in your answer. I found the PDT in http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt/downloads and I don't know if it is what you are talking about.

Comment: You don't get [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with PDT bundled - you get the most appropriate distribution of Eclipse Juno for your usage, then add [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) from the page listing all items included in the Juno release (the versions at the Zend link may be outdated) and possibly [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) if it's not included in the base Eclipse you downloaded).

Answer (score 0):

When sharing a working copy between multiple Subversion clients, all must be at the same major.minor version number. EasyEclipse is looking for a working copy that has been created with a Subversion client earlier than 1.7, because it apparently bundles an older version of the libraries.

I know nothing about EasyEclipse but looking at their ["news" page](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/news/index.html), it appears to be abandoned. You'll either need to roll back TortoiseSVN to a release of similar vintage (and dump/reload your repository, since it sounds like you're not using a Subversion server), or upgrade your PHP IDE to something that's actively being maintained and up to speed with current releases.